# how to clear varnish cache for a drupal view?

Tags: drupal-6, varnish, pressflow

We have a pressflow6 site in acqua hosting service.we have varnish cache enabled.for clearing the cache on drupal views we used cache actions module. with rules.but after adding a content in to a category the view is updating for the logged in users.but not updating for anonymous users,i think the varnish cache is not getting cleared with my rule on cache actions. how to clear varnish cache for a perticular view in drupal/pressflow,and custom code is there to clear the cache, please help me.

Thanks,
Raghu

Answer (score 1):

Many people use Purge and Expire.

See:  http://www.acquia.com/blog/when-and-how-caching-can-save-your-drupal-site

and

http://drupal.org/project/purge